# increasing and decreasing RV height depending on another RV scrolling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-animation

I want to achieve the following behavior -

https://ezgif.com/optimize/ezgif-6-66c61806b01c.gif

here he is my XML file -

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_marketplace_root_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="7dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_marketplace_main_linear_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.twoverte.views.ClearableAutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/fragment_marketplace_searchview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="14dp"
            android:completionThreshold="0"
            android:hint="@string/fragment_marketplace_search_hint"
            android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
            android:inputType="text|textAutoCorrect"
            android:maxLength="25"
            android:textIsSelectable="false"
            android:textSelectHandle="@xml/empty_shape"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="1dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="1dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fragment_marketplace_discover_products_from_myverte_textview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/noto_sans"
            android:text="@string/fragment_marketplace_discover_products_from_myverte"
            android:textSize="17sp" />

        <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/fragment_marketplace_vendors_nested_scrollview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/fragment_marketplace_vendors_recycler_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="14dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                tools:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
                tools:listitem="@layout/fragment_marketplace_vendor_row_item" />

        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>


        <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/fragment_marketplace_featured_products_nested_scroll_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/fragment_marketplace_featured_products_textview"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/very_light_grey"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/noto_sans"
                    android:paddingStart="14dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="14dp"
                    android:paddingTop="15dp"
                    android:paddingEnd="14dp"
                    android:text="@string/fragment_marketplace_featured_products"
                    android:textSize="17sp"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    tools:visibility="visible" />

                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/fragment_marketplace_products_recycler_view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="@color/very_light_grey"
                    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager"
                    tools:listitem="@layout/fragment_marketplace_products_row_item" />

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/activity_product_page_bottom_view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="70dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
                    android:background="@color/light_black"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    tools:visibility="visible" />


            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I have tried SO MANY combinations with `setOnScrollChangeListener` and `addOnScrollListener` and nothing works as expected.

The needed result is to have the ability to increase and decrease the top RV up to a cap.

The decrease should be done when scrolling the bottom RV downwards while the increase is being done when scrolling up.

If someone can assist me with this I would literally kiss his legs, I have been investing so many hours trying to crack how to make this behavior that I am sick of it.

edit

the needed animation -

[image]

Comment: Alright, so you kind of want to look at something called [CollapsingToolbarLayout](https://material.io/develop/android/components/collapsing-toolbar-layout/), the thing that makes that behavior possible `app:layout_scrollFlags`

Let me know if it is what you're searching for so I post the answer

Comment: @Nizar true, but please keep in mind that I need to have only a specific element (horizontal RV) that collapses into itself up to a specific height and expands back to a specific height - not collapse completly and also not collapsing the other elements above it as shown in the gif I created

Comment: Yeah, I know what I'm.talking about, you can do that with the CollapsingToolbarLayout by utilizing the ScrollFlags, I can cook up a demo for you tomorrow

Comment: That would be awesome - waiting for your help.

Comment: @Nizar any news regrading the demo ?

Comment: Yessir, working on it rn, I have a small isuee with it ngl, but the final result should be what you expect. I'll post the demo as an answer once it is done

Comment: Can you please upload the gif (example) again ?

Comment: @Nizar done I have edited the main post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured it out. I will share the code for the XML file as it is first, then explain everything about it later.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="256dp"
            android:minHeight="132dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:titleEnabled="false"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap">

            <View
                android:id="@+id/blue_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="128dp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0"
                android:layout_gravity="top"/>

            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:id="@+id/pink_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="128dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="1"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom">

                <View
                    android:layout_width="2000dp"
                    android:minWidth="2000dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@color/colorAccent"/>

            </HorizontalScrollView>

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

> Note: I used `View` with different colors in order to preview different segments in the Layout. I also used `HorizontalScrollView` in order to showcase something like a `RecyclerView` as in the gif you uploaded.

---

Alright, so first, we need to create a `CollapsingToolbarLayout` with `layout_scrollFlags`.

- we use `scroll` flag must be enabled for any scroll effects to take into effect
- we use `snap` flag to determine what to do when a view only has been partially reduced. If scrolling ends and the view size has been reduced to less than 50% of its original, then this view to return to its original size. If the size is greater than 50% of its sized, it will disappear completely.
- we use `exitUntilCollapsed` along with `minHeight` in order to collapse the `Toolbar` down to the specified `minHeight`

We want the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` to have:

- `layout_height` set to the *expanded* height of the `Toolbar`
- `minHeight` set to the *collapsed* height of the `Toolbar`

> In this case, since we want the `HorizontalScrollView` (`pink_view`) *only* to get smaller in *height*, we set the `minHeight` to the [ *height* of `blue_view` + smaller *height* of `pink_view` ]
>
> Therefore, since `blue_view` will remain `128dp` and we want `pink_view` to go down to `4dp`, we set the `minHeight` to `132dp`.
>
> So here is a small example. Assume the `blue_view` is like `100dp` and the `pink_view` is initially `100dp`. So that's how we want it to show at first, *but when I start scrolling* we want the `pink_view` to go down to `20dp` and the `blue_view` will stay at `100dp`.
>
> Therefore, `layout_height` will be `200dp` and the `minHeight` will be 120dp.

---

Now, we want the `HorizontalScrollView` or the `pink_view` to collapse with the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` *height*.

So, we add `layout_collapseMode="parallax"` to the `pink_view` such that it scrolls along with the `CollapsingToolbarLayout`.

The `layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier` determines what part of the image (in percent) will be hidden under the bottom content. And here, we want it *all* to be hidden. Therefore, we set it to `1`.

---

Meanwhile, we want the `blue_view` to stay *pinned* to the top. And we also don't want it to be hidden under any bottom content.

So, we add `layout_collapseMode="pin"` to the `blue_view` such that it gets pinned to the top of the `CollapsingToolbarLayout`.

We also add `layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0"` in order to not have it be hidden under any content.

---

> Please note that if the *heights* of the elements exceeds the `minHeight`, the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` will be pushed above the screen. It will then seem as if the height of the top item (here `blue_view`) is decreasing in size.

---

#### Preview:

[image]

---

#### Here is another demo with a `RecyclerView`:

[image]

The XML for the above `RecyclerView` demo is below if anyone is interested.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="256dp"
            android:minHeight="148dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:titleEnabled="false"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap">

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="128dp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0"
                android:layout_gravity="top"/>

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/hv_list"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="128dp"
                android:minHeight="20dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="1"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

---

### Edit : Important thing for RecyclerViews and ViewHolders

To achieve the *height* resize for `RecyclerView` and `ViewHolder`, we have to resize them when the `offset` of the `AppBarLayout` changes on scroll.

> This is because the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` just scrolls the elements inside it under each other instead of actually resizing them.

So, we have to use the `RecyclerView`, called here `hv_list`, and the `AppBarLayout`, called here `app_bar`.

```kotlin
val hv_list: RecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.hv_list)

val app_bar: AppBarLayout = findViewById(R.id.app_bar)
```

After that, we need to remember the original size of the `hv_list`.

```kotlin
val hv_original_height: Int = hv_list.layoutParams.height
```

Finally, we need to set an `OffsetChangedListener` for the `AppBarLayout`. There, we will be changing the *height* of the `RecyclerView` and then give it a *margin bottom* to push it up *only because it has a gravity bottom*.

```kotlin
app_bar.addOnOffsetChangedListener(object : AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener {
    override fun onOffsetChanged(appBarLayout: AppBarLayout, i: Int) {
        hv_list.updateLayoutParams {
            this.height = hv_original_height + i
            (this as CollapsingToolbarLayout.LayoutParams).setMargins(0, 0, 0, abs(i))
        }
    }
})
```

> Make sure that your *itemView* in the `RecyclerView` has *height* of **match_parent**

Comment: Thank you very much, I highly appreciate it. I will check it tomorrow and update you if everything works correctly.

Comment: you showed that example with a View that's inside horizontal nested scroll view, did you check it works with a horizontal RV?

Comment: I didnt, I will now though

Comment: Also, how can I determine how much of the red area will be the minimum value ? I want the top RV to be functional though smaller

Comment: @AlonShlider I added a demo gif for the Horizontal RV. Alright, so you have the `minHeight` of the `CollapsingToolbarLayout`, as I mentioned earlier, it is gonna be the Sum of the Top Element + the Size you want the RV to go down to. For example, the `blue_view` has a Height of `100dp` and I want that to stay fixed. The `pink_view` or the RV has an initial size of `100dp` but I want it to go down to `40dp`. So, the `layout_height` would be `200dp`. But the Minimum Height will be `140dp`.

Comment: how can I make the viewholders with their info resize according to their parent? it seems like the textviews inside your horizontal RV stays the same

Comment: Good point, give me a bit to create a another demo that involves like a background color

Comment: @AlonShlider my bad, you're right, the height of the viewpager is not changing at all. I'll fix that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209094/discussion-between-nizar-and-alon-shlider).

Comment: @AlonShlider I updated my answer, the issue should be resolved now :D